# (Error) Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I tried creating a classification training data but I keep getting an error "FeatureCollection (Error) Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements."
Below is the code; how can I solve this?

```
//Training Data
var training_data = Forest.merge(Agriculture).merge(Water).merge(Urban).merge(Bareland);
print('Training Data',training_data);

//Prediction Bands Landsat
var predictBands_l8 = ['B','G','R','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2','QA_PIXEL'];

//Prediction Bands Sentinel
var predictBands_s2 = ['B','G','R','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2','QA60'];

//Classifier Training Landsat
var classifierTraining_l8 = lsat8.select(predictBands_l8)
                                 .sampleRegions({
                                   collection: training_data,
                                   properties: ['class'],
                                   scale: 10
                                 });
print('Classifier Training Landsat', classifierTraining_l8);

//Classifier Training Sentinel
var classifierTraining_s2 = sent2.select(predictBands_s2)
                                 .sampleRegions({
                                   collection: training_data,
                                   properties: ['class'],
                                   scale: 10
                                 });
print('Classifier Training Sentinel', classifierTraining_s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `print()` (or a few other things, like `.toList()`) on a collection containing over 5000 elements.

That doesn't mean you can't use the collection for other operations, though — just don't try to `print` it entirely (you can print a part of it, or its size).

If you did not intend to produce that many points in your training collection, in which case you should change the `scale` of your `sampleRegions()` to be higher than 10 meters.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification